# How does an array work memory-wise?

Tags: arrays, indexing, language-agnostic

So I've been seeing people looping through arrays in order to search for values, even unique ones.

For exemple, when they want to know if a string exists in an array :

```
for(i;i<=count(theArray);i++) {
    if(theArray[i]=="textImSearching") {theBoolean = true;}
}
```

At first I thought it was just a loss of memory, but the more I ran into it, the less I was confident about it.

What I have been doing everytime is something like having the array indexed by the unique value I would be searching for, so in this case, I would only do :

```
theBoolean = theArray["textImSearching"]!=null;
```

As ryanyuyu pointed out, there is also the .NET Dictionary Object.
I used it aswell instead of the List Object to access the value faster using the key.

Sorry for my poor english and thanks in advance.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The syntax differs by language, but arrays generally allocate a block of memory for items within the array. Looping through an array allows the program to search through each of the memory locations by index

Comment: @leppie None, I just wanted to make it understandable to anyone

Comment: This might pertain only to javascript.  Arrays are much more rigid in other languages (like C#).

Comment: For example, for the syntax resembling `theBoolean = theArray["textImSearching"]!=null;` to work in C#, you would have to be using something that was a `Dictionary` because arrays can't index by a key other than index.

Comment: I do the same in C#, instead of using a List object, I use a Dictionary to access the object faster using a key. But I don't know if it's very effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very generally speaking, an array is a block of memory with values packed into it back to back. For example, if your array contains only one data type and this type is of a defined, fixed length, like an `int[]`, the memory will contain integers packed back to back. Indexing into the array (`arr[i]`) is then as simple as taking the starting memory location of `arr` and adding `i * len(int)` to it to find the specific value you want. That's also why arrays are typically zero-indexed.

This becomes more complex as arrays allow to store heterogenous collections of data, or variable-length data. In some way or another the array index just points to the starting memory location of the data though.

This obviously means that you basically have a large blob of binary data stored in memory. If you want to find any one particular piece of data in it, you have no choice but to iterate through all of it. If you require direct access to a certain piece, you need a direct pointer to its location in memory. Obviously, if you know the array index, that's your pointer. This index can be a string or other data type, in which case the array itself is usually called a dictionary, hashmap, associative array or other things depending on the implementing language. These are usually implemented as a hashmap, in which the key is hashed and associated with a memory address, which points to the actual data. This allows quick direct lookup of the memory location using a meaningful index value.